# access-token claims not set apache openidc header (mod _auth_openidc)

Tags: apache, openid-connect, mod-auth-openidc

I am trying get a claim from access-token. I am getting claims from id-token in header but not from access-token. I have authType as openid-connect as it is Human to web authentication. I get encrypted access-token OIDC_ACCESS_TOKEN but what I want is decrypted access-token in json format and claims added. Is there any configuration I can use from mod_auth_openidc to achieve same ?

Comment: Does your OAuth access token support claims? Some are just opaque binary values. Edit your question with details including the Identity Provider.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in apache conf file:

```
Header set OIDC_access_token "%{OIDC_access_token}e" env=OIDC_access_token
```

Reference: https://github.com/OpenIDC/mod_auth_openidc/issues/76#issuecomment-114924260